# Kafka Java Producer API unable to serialize key as Long or Int

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Here is the Java code for producing data in Kafka:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.*;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ExampleClass {
  private final static String TOPIC = "my-example-topic";
  private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "confbroker:9092";

  private static Producer<Long, String> createProducer() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    return new KafkaProducer<>(props);
  }
  private static void runProducer() throws Exception {
    final Producer<Long, String> producer = createProducer();
    long sensorId = 1001L;
    try {
      for (long index = sensorId; index < sensorId + 5; index++) {
        final ProducerRecord<Long, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, index, "This is sensor no: " + index);
        RecordMetadata metadata = producer.send(record).get();
        System.out.printf("sent record(key=%s value=%s) " + "meta(partition=%d, offset=%d)\n", record.key(),
            record.value(), metadata.partition(), metadata.offset());
      }
    } finally {
      producer.flush();
      producer.close();
    }
  }
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
      runProducer();
  }
}
```

When running console consumer in **Confluent 5.4.0**, I am getting result as:

[image]

The key is gibberish.

How can I produce **Key** of either **Int** or **Long** type.

PS:

=> Same result in **Confluent 5.5** also.

=> Same result with **IntegerSerializer**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console consumer uses StringDeserialisers as default for the key and the value. If you want to deserialise the key as `Long` you have to explicitly mention that in your console-consumer command:

```
--property key.deserializer org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer
```

Comment: thanks @mike for quick reply.....
Just a follow up, is it same for streams also because I created a stream from this topic and rowkey is same gibberish.

Comment: Yes, will be the same. In Kafka everything is stored as Bytes and Kafka itself has no knowledge about how this data is serialised. Your consumer need that knowledge to properly read the data.